# How to manipulate strings in lists?

Tags: python, string, list

I am have been trying to learn how to manipulate lists. Example I have successfully done a simple program that asks the user for a numerical input and returns the corresponding month. Below is an example of what my solution is:

```
months = ['January', 'February',
          'March', 'April', 'May',
          'June', 'July', 'August',
          'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

n = int(input("Enter a value between 1 and 12: "))

# Process & Output:
if 1 <= n <= 12:
    print ("The month is", months[n-1])
else:
    print ("Value is out of the range")
```

My current question is, how would I go about asking the user to pick from the list but by inputting a string rather than an `int` value?

Example:

```
subjects= ['Maths','English','Science','History','Business']
n = (input("What is your favourite subject this semester? "))
```

I would not be able to use the above method because it requires an `int` value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565793/how-to-let-the-user-select-an-input-from-a-finite-list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to let the user select an input from a finite list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565793/how-to-let-the-user-select-an-input-from-a-finite-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to check a string input against the list, you can do it simply using `in`:

```
subjects = ['Maths','English','Science','History','Business']

subj_in = input("What is your favourite subject this semester? ")

if subj_in in subjects:

    print('Your favorite subject is ', subj_in)

else:

    print('Oh, they offer a course for that?')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
subjects= ['Maths','English','Science','History','Business']

n = (input("What is your favourite subject this semester? "))

if n in subjects:
    print('great')
else:
    print('even better')
```

Comment: Wow it was that simple? Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You have already asked the user for the subject. Now you have to find that in subjects list. To do it just use this

```
if n in subjects: 
    print ("valid subject")
else:
    print("invalid subject")
```