# Line-by-Line Lists - Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to give the user of my "Terminal" a list from which they can choose what to do. But when I run my program, it includes the brackets as well. It still runs as normal, but it just looks a bit funny:

```
user_want_to_do = ["Open Google", "Access Files", "Exit Terminal"]
print("\n")
print(user_want_to_do)
opt = input("Please input what you want to do from the list above:")
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: So do you expect the user to type (without any mistake) the exact sentence they want to choose? Doesn't seem user friendly if you ask me. Why not ask them to type a single character (digit?) that identifies the choice?

Comment: Like this: `for e in user_want_to_do: print(e)`?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565793/how-to-let-the-user-select-an-input-from-a-finite-list

Comment: If you don't want the square brackets, then don't try to print a list directly.  Print strings instead.

Comment: I could... but you don't see Windows asking you to type 1 for Files,  2 for Google... It just doesn't seen right. But I see where you're coming from:)

Comment: You haven't specified how you want it to look...

Answer (score 2):

You can just print them as strings by joining them

`" ".join(user_want_to_do)`

A "prettier" solution -

```
user_want_to_do = ["Open Google", "Access Files", "Exit Terminal"]

for i, item in enumerate(user_want_to_do, start=1):
    print(f"{i}. {item}")
```

Prints the list as a numbered list

Comment: Just comes up as an invalid syntax on the last speech marks in the last line.

Comment: @F4TAL_3RR0R.exe There's no invalid syntax in the code (unless you are using python 2.x or a very old python 3 version)

Comment: No, I'm running it on V.3.4.1. It just comes up with an invalid syntax on the final set of speech marks.

Answer (score 1):

You can print without the brackets with unpacking:

```
user_want_to_do = ["Open Google", "Access Files", "Exit Terminal"]

print(*user_want_to_do, sep=", ") # removes quotes as well
```

output:

```
Open Google, Access Files, Exit Terminal
```

If you want them on separate lines instead:

```
print(*user_want_to_do, sep="\n")
```

output:

```
Open Google
Access Files
Exit Terminal
```

If you want to keep the quotes you can map the strings to the `repr` function:

```
print(*map(repr,user_want_to_do), sep=", ")
```

output:

```
'Open Google', 'Access Files', 'Exit Terminal'
```

or strip brackets from the list's representation:

```
print(repr(user_want_to_do).strip('[]'))
```

output:

```
'Open Google', 'Access Files', 'Exit Terminal'
```

Comment: Code doesn't run; it just throws up an error message on "Google".

Comment: Code only has one line and works on my computer.  Did you try to run the sample output ? (I now separated the output in my answer to avoid confusion)

Comment: That does work, yes, but part of the issue is the fact that the speech marks are still included.

Comment: What do you mean by "speech marks" ?  If you're referring to quotes, two of the four solutions I proposed remove them. If not, you should include the exact output you're looking for in your question.