# Ask user for input giving them a list to choose from

Tags: python

I am trying to design a program that calculates total holiday cost for the user.

I want to ask the user for input that gives them a list of options to choose from, e.g.

```
['1: Paris:      £100', 
 '2: Belgium:    £90',
 '3: Denmark:    £90',
 '4: Sydney:     £210',
 '5: Bangkok:    £200',
 '6: Venice:     £100']
```

I've got the input bit:

```
city_flight = input("Please let me know which city you will be flying to:\n ")
```

What I am struggling with is adding the above list to the city_flight string.

Comment: What exact errors is it chucking back?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565793/how-to-let-the-user-select-an-input-from-a-finite-list

Answer (score -1):

You'll probably want something like this:

```
def prompt_choice(prompt, choices):
    for i, choice in enumerate(choices, 1):
        print(f"{i}. {choice}")
    while True:
        try:
            choice = int(input(prompt))
            if 1 <= choice <= len(choices):
                return choices[choice - 1]
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print("Invalid choice")

choices = [
    "Paris:      £100",
    "Belgium:    £90",
    "Denmark:    £90",
    "Sydney:     £210",
    "Bangkok:    £200",
    "Venice:     £100",
]

print(prompt_choice("Please let me know which city you will be flying to:\n ", choices))
```

Note how:

- the choice numbering is done by [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/functions.html#enumerate) so you needn't do it by hand
- there's a `while True` loop to ensure the user chooses an option that is an integer in the range 1..N, that we break out of using `return` when the choice is valid.

The next issue you'll have is that the string returned is the choice as-is and it will be a bit of a chore to split it into the city and the price; it'd be better if the choices were "raw data" and `prompt_choice` could be given a way to format the choice for human consumption... but that's another question.

Answer (score -1):

Easier way I can merely do lambda. Starting from zero to five.

Snippet:

```
l=['0: Paris:      £100', 
 '1: Belgium:    £90',
 '2: Denmark:    £90',
 '3: Sydney:     £210',
 '4: Bangkok:    £200',
 '5: Venice:     £100']

city_flight = {int(input(r"Please let me know which city you will be flying to: "))}
which_flight = list(map(lambda x: l[x],city_flight)) 
 
print(which_flight)
```

Comment: How does this address the question `I want to ask the user for input that gives them a list of options to choose from` ?